# Finding greatest value of a trigonometric expression involving two angles

Tags: physics

> A particle is projected up a plane inclined at an angle $b$ to the
>   horizontal, the angle of projection being $a$ above the horizontal.
>
> Part 1: If the initial speed of projection is $V$ m/s show that 
>   range, $C$, on the inclined plane is given by: 
>   $$C= 2 V^2 \frac{\sin(a-b) \cos(a)}{g\cos(b)^2}$$
>
> Part 2: Determine the maximum range ($C$ max) on the plane and the 
>   value of $b$ for which this occurs.
>   **maximising the trigonometric function is the main problem here**

Here is a diagram:

[image]

Comment: $C$ is unbounded because cos can be made infinitessimally small.

Comment: Even if the angles have to be in the range 0 to 90 degrees, the cosine can be made infinitesimally small. $cos(90-\epsilon)\approx\epsilon$.

Comment: This actually came from a question about a particle being projected up an inclined plane (if that helps). The question says: A particle is projected up a plane inclined at an angle b to the horizontal, the angle of projection being a above the horizontal. part 1: if the initial speed of projection is V m/s show that range, C, on the inclined plane is given by: C= 2V^2sin(a-b)cos(a)/(cos(b)^2) part 2: determine the maximum range (R max) on the plane and the value of b for which this occurs.

Comment: sorry im not sure how to post a diagram. its just a 2 dimensional model of a projectile being fired onto a ramp

Comment: sorry i wasnt really precise saying 'algebraically' analysis is what i mean

Comment: I am such an idiot - very important is to say that a must be greater than b, because the particle must land on the plane, the angle of projection has to greater than the angle of the ramp sorry for all confusion created. thanks for all responses so far.

Comment: Im sorry, C and R are the same thing. it was a typing error, please excuse me. Range is defined as the distance along the inclined plane between the base of the plane and the point where the projectile lands on the plane.

Comment: thank you for making the original post easier to understand

Comment: This is a fairly straightforward problem where you can use the horizontal & vertical displacements at time t

Comment: @Jim thanks for the diagram. You can unclutter this by deleting outdated comments using the tiny "x".

Comment: @Yaitzme Yes, but I at least needed a diagram to understand the problem. Now it is just a matter of physics. See how late that not unimportant gravitational acceleration $g$ entered the question?

Comment: just to clarify, part 1 I understand, what I'm interested in is how to find the relationship between a and b that gives greatest C, (first equation) and then apply this to get the max 'range' for a given v. thanks so much for responses

Comment: I think $a$ and $b$ are reversed on the figure. You want $b,$ not $a,$ to be the angle between the inclined plane and horizontal, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a diagram of the problem with a few helpful elements added:

[image]

The figure illustrates the fact that if not for the influence of gravity,
the projectile would simply travel a distance $Vt$ along the line at an angle $a$
above the horizontal in a certain time $t,$
but because of gravity, the projectile is deflected downward a distance
$\frac 12 gt^2,$ 
so it ends up at the intersection of the blue parabola and the vertical red line.
This point is the landing point on the inclined surface if we choose $t$
to be the amount of time the projectile is in flight before striking that surface.

Now we do a little trigonometry. We draw a right triangle with the
segment $Vt$ as the hypotenuse and an extension of segment $C$ as one of the legs.
The vertical red line cuts a smaller right triangle from this triangle;
the smaller triangle has hypotenuse $\frac 12 gt^2$
and angle $b$ at the topmost vertex, hence the adjacent leg is $\frac 12 gt^2 \cos b.$
But that leg is also the leg opposite the angle $a-b$ of the larger right triangle,
so we have
$$Vt \sin (a-b) = \frac 12 gt^2 \cos b.$$

Now consider the horizontal segment in the figure, which is the leg
adjacent to angle $b$ in a right triangle whose hypotenuse is $C,$
so its length is $C \cos b,$
but it is also the leg adjacent to angle $a$ in a right triangle 
whose hypontenuse is $Vt.$
This gives us
$$C \cos b = Vt \cos a.$$

From these two equations we can conclude that
$$\left(\frac 12 gt^2 \cos b\right)(C \cos b) = (Vt \sin (a-b))(Vt \cos a).$$

We have already assumed that $t > 0,$ so we can cancel factors of $t.$
Assuming $b$ is less than a right angle, $\cos b > 0$ as well, 
and we can assume $g > 0.$
We can use these facts to isolate $C$ on one side of the equation.
The result is
$$C = \frac{2V^2 \sin (a-b) \cos a}{g \cos^2 b}.$$

The second part of the problem is to maximize $C.$
At least one version of the posted question allows us to vary $b$ in order to maximize $C.$
But we can make $C$ as large as we want merely by keeping $a$ constant and
letting $b$ approach $-\frac\pi2$ radians--that is, incline the plane as steeply
downwards as we like, but never quite vertical (because then there is no second
intersection of the trajectory with the plane, and $C$ is undefined).
We can even allow $a$ to vary and still $C$ is unbounded as long as $a$ 
is not too close to $b.$

So I will answer a more interesting question, which I suspect is what was
meant to be asked: find $a$ that maximizes $C$ 
for given constant values of $V,\ g,$ and $b.$

To solve this, observe the trigonometric identity
$$\sin x - \sin y = 2 \sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right).$$
Conveniently, there is a product of a sine and cosine in the quantity we want
to maximize. So we would like to have
$$\begin{eqnarray}
a - b &=& \frac12(x-y), \\
a     &=& \frac12(x+y).
\end{eqnarray}$$
Solving for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a$ and $b,$ we find that
$$\begin{eqnarray}
x &=& 2a - b, \\
y &=& b.
\end{eqnarray}$$
Therefore, we can use the identity to substitute for $\sin (a-b) \cos a$ as follows:
$$C = \frac{2V^2}{g \cos^2 b} (\sin (2a-b) - \sin b).$$

But according to the conditions of the problem, everything on the right-hand side
of this equation is a constant except for $a.$
We therefore maximize $C$ by maximizing $\sin (2a-b),$
which occurs when $2a-b$ is a right angle.
Measuring in radians, that gives us $$a = \frac12\left(\frac\pi2 + b\right).$$
Measured in degrees, $a = 45 + \frac12 b.$

Answer (score 0):

Here's me having a go at it:

Now, let the particle hit the plane after time *t*.

Horizontal Displacement = $C*\cos b$ 
Vertical Displacement = $C*\sin b$

Horizontal velocity = $V*\cos a$ (along positive x-axis) 
Vertical velocity = $V*\sin a$ (along positive y-axis)

After time t:

$V*\cos a*t = C*\cos b$ . . . (1) 
$V*\sin a *t - 0.5*g*t^2 = C*\sin b$ . .  . (2)

From (1) obtain the value of $t$ and plug it into (2) and rearrange to answer Qn 1